# integer division to float result

Tags: java, floating-point, division

I have to divide two integers and get a float as result
My Code:

```
Float ws;
int i = Client.getInstance().getUser().getGespielteSpiele() -Client.getInstance().getUser().getGewonneneSpiele();
int zahl1 = Client.getInstance().getUser().getGewonneneSpiele();

ws = new Float((zahl1 / i));
```

I check the values with the debugger

```
i = 64

zahl1 = 22

ws = 0.0
```

Why is the result of `ws` 0.0? What I should do to get the correct float?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you divide two `int`s you perform integer division, which, in this case will result in 22/64 = 0. Only once this is done are you creating a `float`. And the `float` representation of `0` is `0.0`. If you want to perform floating point division, you should cast **before** dividing:

```
ws = ((float) zahl1) / i;
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, this solution is right and good explained :)

Answer (score 3):

`zahl1 / i` is computed as int division and then converted to Float by the `Float` constructor. For floating point division, cast one of the operands to `float` or `double`:

```
ws = new Float((float)zahl1 / i);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're doing integer division,you need to change the int value as float at first.

```
float ws = (float) zahl1 / i;
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
float ws = (float)zahl1/i;
```